# model.frame function does not react on AsIs object in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract variables passed in formula in the way they were passed to be modified, i.e. with `log` transformation or with `?AsIs` operator that takes into the n-th power but `model.frame` looks like not to react on this `?AsIs` operator in R

```
> library(survival)
> formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ mspike + log(mspike) + I(mspike)^2 + I(mspike)^3
> head(model.frame(formula, data = mgus))
  Surv(futime, death) mspike log(mspike) I(mspike)
1                748     2.0   0.6931472         2
2               6751     1.3   0.2623643       1.3
3                277     1.3   0.2623643       1.3
4               1815     1.8   0.5877867       1.8
5               2587     1.4   0.3364722       1.4
6                563     1.8   0.5877867       1.8
```

Does anyone know how to extract modified variables for `I(mspike)^2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `I()` function is used in R's formula language to "escape" operators that have a special meaning in the formula language. So, to include the square of a variable in your model, you need to specify the term as `I(mspike^2)`. Then it also shows up in the model frame:

```
data(iris)
m1 <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + log(Petal.Width) +     I(Petal.Length^2), data = iris)
head(model.frame(m1))
  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length log(Petal.Width) I(Petal.Length^2)
1         3.5          5.1       -1.6094379              1.96
2         3.0          4.9       -1.6094379              1.96
3         3.2          4.7       -1.6094379              1.69
4         3.1          4.6       -1.6094379              2.25
5         3.6          5.0       -1.6094379              1.96
6         3.9          5.4       -0.9162907              2.89
```

Comment: Thanks... My mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
I(mspike)^2
```

use:

```
I(mspike^2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(model.frame(formula, data = mgus)$`I(mspike)`)^2
```

Comment: Assumming you don't know the names?

Comment: That you should extract the from formula.